# How do I find the max value in a file using bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a temperature.txt file, and I have to find the max value (the 5th one), and print the location (first 2 values), the date (3rd value) and time (4th value).

```
47.6498634,19.1404118,2002.05.18,08:32,-1
48.6498634,19.1404118,2003.05.18,09:32,28
49.6498634,19.1404118,2004.05.18,01:32,17
46.6498634,19.1404118,2005.05.18,02:32,15
45.6498634,19.1404118,2006.05.18,03:32,9
44.6498634,19.1404118,2007.05.18,04:32,31
43.6498634,19.1404118,2008.05.18,05:32,23
42.6498634,19.1404118,2009.05.18,06:32,13
```

Comment: Your "text" file seems to be a CSV; copy/paste a few lines of it in your question (as code) instead of linking to an image. BTW, why do you flag your question as PowerShell if only Bash is concerned?

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort -t, -r -n -k5,5 temperature.txt | awk -F"," '{print $5,$1,$2,$3,$4}' | head -1
```

output

```
31 44.6498634 19.1404118 2007.05.18 04:32
```